# Error Message FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python-3.x

I'm new to Python and found already good hints in this forum, seems to be great, thanks a lot!

Now I'm struggling with a problem and tried already several things without success.
Maybe you can help me?

```
    #Create Private Key
    strServerFileKey = strBackupPathKS + strOSTypePathSep + strPrivateKey
    print("strServerFileKey is: " + strServerFileKey)
    #openSSLArgs = " genrsa -out " + strServerFileKey + " " + str(intKeySize)
    openSSLArgs = " genrsa -out " + strServerFileKey + " " + str(intKeySize)
    print("OpenSSLArgs are " + openSSLArgs)
    
    if os.name == 'posix':
        strComKey = strOpenSSLPath + openSSLArgs
        print("Path is " + strComKey)
    else:
        strComKey = "\"" + strOpenSSLPath + "\"" + openSSLArgs
        #strComKey = "\"" + strOpenSSLPath + "\"" + openSSLArgs
        #strComKey = strOpenSSLPath + "\"" + openSSLArgs
    subprocess.run(strComKey )
```

Important is the part with
`if os.name == 'posix':`
because it's a Linux Server in this case and the part
`subprocess.run(strComKey )`

If I run this part of the code I get the following failure message:

File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1364, in _execute_child
raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/app/sim/tsim/pw/apache/bin/openssl genrsa -out /app/sim/SSL_Certificate/AutoCertCreate/ss008783.key 3072': '/app/sim/tsim/pw/apache/bin/openssl genrsa -out /app/sim/SSL_Certificate/AutoCertCreate/ss008783.key 3072'

If I run that part that gives an error message manually it works perfect:

/app/sim/tsim/pw/apache/bin/openssl genrsa -out /app/sim/SSL_Certificate/AutoCertCreate/ss008783.key 3072

Any idea where the prblem could be?
If you need more information, please let me know, it's Python 3.6

Thanks a lot, have a good day and stay safe

Cheers

Markus

Comment: where and how are you assigning the parts of the directory path?

Comment: You seem to be lumping multiple strings into a single argument to [`subprocess.run()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess).

Comment: @HenryJames at the beginning of the script I've defined some variables. I have the script in the office, but I can explain it here

Comment: @HenryJames:
For the part
 strServerFileKey = strBackupPathKS + strOSTypePathSep + strPrivateKey
I've defined something similar like that:
strBackupPathKS = /app/sim/SSL_Certificate/AutoCertCreate
strOSTypePathSep  = "/"
strPrivateKey = ss008783.key  (is hostname and .key

Comment: @greybeard, yes I do, but that should not be a problem, no?

Comment: Well, inspect the string from the error message closely. Find a simple, working example of `subprocess.run()` use. Revisit its documentation.

Comment: @greybeard I've everal other subprocess running without problem and it must be a problem somehow with the string. I tried many different things, no chance so far. This is the reason I'm asking here :-)
And like Iive mentioned, the output string is ok, because if I copy the failure message and let it run manually, it works

Comment: Please copy&paste at least one kick-off of one `other subprocess running without problem` and/or *exactly how* you `let it run manually` into your question.

Comment: @greybeard, maybe to clarify it more in detail, like already mentioned, this subprocess is the first one in the code used on Linux where I have the problem. On Windows all subprocesses are running well. Here is a example:
    strComKey = "\"" + strOpenSSLPath + "\"" + openSSLArgs
    subprocess.run(strComKey)
That one that I run manually is already in the question:
/app/sim/tsim/pw/apache/bin/openssl genrsa -out /app/sim/SSL_Certificate/AutoCertCreate/ss008783.key 3072
That is also the messge that is in the Error Output

Comment: Ok, I think I've found the solution:
I've to handle it with

    args = shlex.split(strComKey)
    p = subprocess.Popen(args)

then it works, now I've only to find out how I can add a Carriage Return after p is running, because if I run the code, I've to click enter that it continuous

Comment: `one that I run manually is already in the question` that is *what*. In the previous prompt to improve your question, I advised to copy&paste *exactly **how***: What does `run manually` boil down to? No one here can look over your shoulder.